# Laravel 7 not finding with scopes

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model called Shift on my application, and I've defined my relationships and scopes on it like this:

Relationship:

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ShiftStatus::class);
}
```

With scope:

```
public function scopeWithStatus($query)
{
    $query->with('status');
}
```

Now, when I retrieve shifts and try to call these scopes, I do the following:

```
$shifts = Shift::all()
            ->withStatus()
            ->withProfession()
            ...
            ->get();

        return response([
            'message' => 'Shifts retrieved.',
            'shifts' => $shifts
        ]);
```

However, I get this error...

```
"message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::withStatus does not exist.",
```

I'm not sure why this is happening? It should pick up the scope shouldn't it?

Comment: remove `all()` from query it make query instance to Collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call Shift::[all()](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all) you get all the shifts table record from db as a collection , then you load the relation on that collection which makes that error.

you should not be loading the result from db unless  your query is ready, you should tell the query builder to load the relation then call the result:

```
$shifts = Shift::withStatus()
            ->withProfession()
            ...
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use a query scope in a Collection, since query scope is a concept used in Eloquent to add constraints to a database query while Collections are just a collection of things (data, objects, etc).
So, remove all(). Also i think you are missing return statement in scope (not a part of this question, but you need to update the code )